# Store2 fails to map member fields during account creation in checkout

Tags: expresso-store

I know that not being able to create accounts during checkout was a bug in the initial release of Store 2 which was fixed in a recent update, so I'm wondering if this is a bug as well, or if i shall continue troubleshooting? This was working for me in the previous version of Store (pre 2), but i could still of course be doing something wrong.

I have of course created and mapped the member fields in ee/store admin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are no known issues regarding mapping member fields. I suggest you email support@exp-resso.com if you haven't already and we can take a look at your site directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in fact solved in the latest update. I was messing up the templating.

I got it working with input type="text" id="billing_first_name" name="billing_first_name" class="{if error:billing_first_name}error{/if}" value="{billing_first_name}"

I feel silly. Still new to EE. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in the recent Store 2.0.3 release. For all other bug fixes you can take a look at the [Release Notes](https://exp-resso.com/docs/release_notes.html#store_203).

Comment: Hmm.. I am using 2.0.3, but the problem is still there. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmmmm... What version of EE are you using? Are you mapping to standard member fields or are you using ZooVistor to map to channel fields? Can you make sure that you have run Module Updates from Add-ons > Modules. Are you using any other member add-ons that might be conflicting?

Comment: If you are still under development you can also try uninstalling and reinstalling to see if that solves the issue. Unfortunately how EE handles an uninstall I would not recommend doing that if you have a lot of data/orders as it will be erased.

Comment: Will try this when i get home from work today and report back, thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem was that instead of using for example {field:billing_first_name} to spit out the first name, I was using the following

input type="text" id="billing_first_name" name="billing_first_name" class="{if error:billing_first_name}error{/if}" value=""

I did it that way because I want to apply an error class to the input. Is there another way to do this?